# Bulk Insert of CSV still has double quotes it in SQL server database 2019

Tags: sql, sql-server

Please help. This is the Bulk insert code to insert Employee data into SQL server 2019.The data is being inserted. but still with quotes. How to insert data without quotes?
Please let me know what wrong AM' I doing?

```
BULK INSERT dbo.tblActiveDirData
FROM 'E:\EmployeeData\ATadUserlistDB.csv'
WITH 
  (
    DATAFILETYPE = 'char',
     FIRSTROW = 2,
     FIELDTERMINATOR= ',',
    ROWTERMINATOR = '\n'
     
)
```

Comment: You didn't specify that fields are quoted

Answer (score 1):

This worked:

```
BULK INSERT Test_CSV
FROM  'C:\MyCSV.csv' 
WITH ( FORMAT='CSV');
```

No other other code with field terminator, datafiletype was needed